# Using Redis with Guzzle's Cache Plugin

Tags: caching, laravel, laravel-4, redis, guzzle

I've got a laravel application that is using Redis for caching and session storage. Data pulls in from an API using Guzzle. I'm trying to set up the Guzzle client to use it's built in cache plugin, and would like to use Redis as the storage engine, rather than the file system storage that Doctrine seems to use.

Guzzle documentation says to set the plugin up in the code like this:

```
$cachePlugin = new CachePlugin(array(
    'storage' => new DefaultCacheStorage(
        new DoctrineCacheAdapter(
            new FilesystemCache('/path/to/cache/files')
        )
    )
));
```

Since I interact with the cache in the Laravel side of things just using the built in Cache object, I'm not sure how to translate that knowledge for setting up this aspect of Guzzle.

Since I can find absolutely no information on Redis with Guzzle, I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you need an additional library which can be installed via [composer](https://getcomposer.org/):

https://github.com/M6Web/RedisBundle/tree/master

They define an adapter for Redis which you can couple with the cache plugin:

https://github.com/M6Web/RedisBundle/tree/master#guzzle-redis-cache-adapter